# Aggregate values with corresponding counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe something like:

```
my_df = 

chr   PI
2     5
2     5
2     5
2     6
2     6
2     8
2     8
2     8
2     8
2     8
3     5
3     5
3     5
3     5
3     9
3     9
3     9
3     9
3     9
3     9
3     9
3     7
3     7
3     4
......
......
```

I want to convert it into new dataframe that contains new information on the dataframe, something like:

- chr:       unique chromosomes
- unq_PI :   number of unique PIs within each chromosome
- PIs    :   list of "PI" values in that chromosome
- PI_freq:   length of each "PI" in the respective chromosome

**So, expected output would be:**

```
chr   unq_PI   PIs        PI_freq
2     3        5,6,8      3,2,5
3     4        5,9,7,4    4,7,2,1
```

I was thinking something like:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'chr': my_df['chr'].unique(),
         'unq_PI': my_df('chr')['unq_PI'].nunique()),
         'PIs': .......................,
         'PI_freq': ..................})

The only code that works is for `chr` when used alone; any additional code just throws an error. How can I fix this?
```

Comment: if you post the error it would be helpful. At first sight, it looks like you don't have same no of unique values for each column.

Comment: Is ordering in `PIs` and `PI_freq` values important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order is important use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.value_counts().astype(str).reindex(x.unique())
    i = ['unq_PI','PIs','PI_freq']
    return pd.Series([x.nunique(), ','.join(a.index), ','.join(a)], index=i)
df = df['PI'].astype(str).groupby(df['chr'], sort=False).apply(f).unstack().reset_index()
```

Another solution:

```
df = (df.rename(columns={'PI' : 'PIs'})
        .groupby(['chr','PIs'], sort=False)
        .size()
        .rename('PI_freq')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .astype(str)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(','.join)
        .assign(unq_PI=lambda x: x['PIs'].str.count(',') + 1)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=['chr','unq_PI','PIs','PI_freq'])
       )
```

---

```
print (df)
   chr  unq_PI      PIs  PI_freq
0    2       3    5,6,8    3,2,5
1    3       4  5,9,7,4  4,7,2,1
```

**Explanation**:

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by both columns and get [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for unique values of `PI` and their frequencies per group. Then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for second level of `MultiIndex` to column and cast to string:

```
df1 = (df.rename(columns={'PI' : 'PIs'})
        .groupby(['chr','PIs'], sort=False)
        .size()
        .rename('PI_freq')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .astype(str)

       )
print (df1)
    PIs PI_freq
chr            
2     5       3
2     6       2
2     8       5
3     5       4
3     9       7
3     7       2
3     4       1
```

Then `groupby` by index by `level=0` and aggreate `join`:

```
df1 = (df.rename(columns={'PI' : 'PIs'})
        .groupby(['chr','PIs'], sort=False)
        .size()
        .rename('PI_freq')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .astype(str)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(','.join)
       )
print (df1)
         PIs  PI_freq
chr                  
2      5,6,8    3,2,5
3    5,9,7,4  4,7,2,1
```

Last get number of unique values by [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column, [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for custom order of final columns:

```
df1 = (df.rename(columns={'PI' : 'PIs'})
        .groupby(['chr','PIs'], sort=False)
        .size()
        .rename('PI_freq')
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .astype(str)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(','.join)
        .assign(unq_PI=lambda x: x['PIs'].str.count(',') + 1)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=['chr','unq_PI','PIs','PI_freq'])
       )

print (df1)
   chr  unq_PI      PIs  PI_freq
0    2       3    5,6,8    3,2,5
1    3       4  5,9,7,4  4,7,2,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` + `value_counts`, followed by `groupby` + `agg`.

```
v = (df.groupby('chr')
       .PI
       .apply(pd.Series.value_counts, sort=False)
       .reset_index(level=1)
       .astype(str)
       .groupby(level=0)
       .agg(','.join)
       .rename(columns={'level_1' : 'PIs', 'PI' : 'PI_freq'})
)
```

This doesn't account for the count of unique values, that can be computed using `groupby` + `nunique`:

```
v.insert(0, 'unq_PI', df.groupby('chr').PI.nunique())
```

```
v 

     unq_PI      PIs  PI_freq
chr                          
2         3    5,6,8    3,2,5
3         4  4,5,7,9  1,4,2,7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `value_counts`

```
yourdf=pd.concat([s.nunique(),s.value_counts().to_frame('n').reset_index().groupby('chr').agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.astype(str)))],1)
yourdf
Out[90]: 
    PI       PI        n
chr                     
2    3    8,5,6    5,3,2
3    4  9,5,7,4  7,4,2,1

yourdf.columns=['unq_PI','PIs','PI_freq']
yourdf
Out[93]: 
     unq_PI      PIs  PI_freq
chr                          
2         3    8,5,6    5,3,2
3         4  9,5,7,4  7,4,2,1
```